# Issue importing python module in VS Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I am just starting out in Python and wanted to try GUI using tkinter. The module is installed using pip globally on my System and separately within a venv in my project folder. i can run my program perfectly inside of the console using python3, but i cannot get it to work inside of VS Code. Currently i even get tool tips for tkinter objects. When i try to run it, it just can't import it and raises an error. I am using VS Code on Linux and installed it with flatpack.

I am guessing the problem is somewhere in my venv, so i attached a screenshot of it and my code. If i use tk for the import i do not even get tool tips and it crashes at line 3. In the version i posted it crashes in line 1. (i am using the venv python Interpreter)

[venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suNnf.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was more Linux related, i had VS installed as a flatpack. The problem was solved by installing the official MS package.